# How to write html code in <option> tag of <select> tag?

Tags: html

I have  object that i want to show data to user. but i want to write html code in option tag like this.How can i do that?

```
<select id="ddl" >
  <option value="1501" Director="test" Duration="">
  <table><tr><td>.1.</td><td>.2.</td></tr></table>
  </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: you can't you would have to create a custom control using js and css. You can look at the source code of the jquery plugin 'Chosen' http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and see how they make their custom select inputs.

Comment: Do you want to put markup in the option tag, or render html source in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. [`<option>` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) aren't allowed any other elements as children, they have *Content model: Text.*

The closest you could come would be to use something other than a `<select>`, put radio buttons inside it instead of `<option>`, and add a pile of JavaScript and CSS to add the drop down effect and make it look like a select.

Comment: @OptimusPrime — The question is about putting markup in the element, not about rendering HTML source code in it. If it was about the latter, involving JavaScript would be a terrible idea since you could write `&lt;` and friends directly.

Comment: Ahhhh right. `&lt;`. +1